# Word for person without children

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Is there a word (adjective or noun) for people who has no children, just like *single* for people who is not married?

I looked on the internet and found the word *[childfree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Childfree)*, but it seems to describe a lifestyle preference instead of being a simple statement of fact.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The word is **childless**.

This is neither positive nor negative in tone, and does not imply whether the couple remains without children by choice or by some other circumstance (e.g. one partner might be *sterile*.)

Comment: Some native speakers regard "childless" and "childfree" to have implications; others regard "childless" to be neutral and "childfree" to imply "by choice".  You will find many discussions online arguing this exact point.

Comment: Note that many people would very much disagree that "childless" doesn't have a tone. Frankly, we don't have a commonly used 100% neutral word for it. The common usage is to say the phrase along the lines of "doesn't have children."

Answer (score 2):

You can say "childless". There are probably other alternatives.

Comment: That's exactly the word and a good answer; a dictionary reference and an example would make it a great one.

Answer (score 0):

Barren
• archaic
(of a woman) infertile.
synonyms:   infertile, sterile, childless; technicalinfecund
"a barren woman"
antonyms:   fertile

• (of a female animal) not pregnant or unable to become so.

Comment: It's certainly not a current word for having no children, but readers of Shakespeare or the bible are likely to come across it.

Answer (score 0):

There is the word **nulliparous**, which is a medical term for not having children (whether by choice or by infertility).

[Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/nulliparous) defines the adjective as:

> **nulliparous** (*adj.*) Of the condition of a nullipara.

while *nullipara* is defined as:

> **nullipara** (*noun*) `obstetrics` A woman who has never given birth.

This is not a word you would encounter very often, and other options (like *childless*) would usually be more appropriate for everyday conversation.

Comment: You will only find this in medical context, where it is related to "nulligravid" (never pregnant) and unrelated to whether any of the children are still living.

Comment: 1) Having given birth doesn't mean you currently have children. 2) This is woman specific, and OP specifically asked for a word for people in general. So this is doubly not applicable to the question.